# Sharepoint Designer - Trigger Approval WF with specific changes to an item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval-process

Is there a way I can trigger an approval workflow only with a change in a specific column of an item in the sharepoint site and not by every change to any column of the item?

I am working with sharepoint designer 2010 and received the below response to my comment, however it is not clear to me, can someone help me by either writing a step by step or referring me to a link in this site?

Answer (score 0):

This typically needs to be done by creating a second, hidden, column for the previous status. When your workflows complete, it updates this hidden field to the current status. Then when the item is edited, you put in your first step to check if the status column equals your hidden status column. If it does, you terminate the workflow. If it does not, you need to then move onto your approval logic.

Comment: Hi PirateEric,thank you for your prompt response.  I understand the concept of what you're telling me but do not know how to apply it in sharepoint designer.  Let me see if I got it right: i need to create a hidden column in the sharepoint site and copy the current status into it.  That would be step 1.  Now, i don't know how to create the steps for the workflow that you're telling me, could you maybe walk me through that step by step? I appreciate your patience and your help.